# Alarm manager starting after device reboot

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an alarm manager, that should run in the end of every year. It's work fine, but when I rebooted my device, this event start after my device robot, which, in my case, clearing my database. But I want my alarmmanager to go into the background after rebooting the device and worked at the end of the year, and not immediately:

device reboot -> alarm manager starting -> not do everything till the end of the year -> end of the year-> trigger

MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            AndroidInjection.inject(this);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        runFullYearTimer();
}

    private void runFullYearTimer() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullYearCleaning.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 31);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);

        presenter.putIntInStorage(YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));

    manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

}

FullYearCleaning.class

```
public class FullYearCleaning extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Inject
    GeneralStorageHelper generalStorageHelper;

    @Inject
    CountryDaoModel countryDaoModel;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this, context);

        Log.d(TAG, "Running ending event!");

        countryDaoModel.clearCountriesValues();
        generalStorageHelper.putIntIntStorage(SP_HALF_YEAR, NO_HALF_YEAR_NOTIFICATION);
        generalStorageHelper.putIntIntStorage(SP_COMPLETE_YEAR, NO_ALL_YEAR_NOTIFICATION);
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<receiver
    android:name=".model.FullYearCleaning"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: It's normal that the db is cleared after every boot as you've set it up that way with your intent-filter. Why did you add these?

Comment: i would think you should use sharedPreferences so you dont loose data after reboot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of using the same broadcast receiver class for boot completed and alarm triggered
There are two solutions to overcome this

1. Having separate classes for Boot complete and alarm trigger
2. adding Extras to pending intent and depending on intent extras in on receive you can choose what to do.

   `if(intent.hasExtra("ALARM")){
      //clear values
   }else{
      // create alarm here 
   }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm use SharefPrefence to save timemilis and alarm id.
after Device reboot I call BroadcastReceiver and create new alarm with timemilis and alarm id from SharedPrefence.

`if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
      //create alarm
}`

Hope this help you.